# Auto select Magento free shipping radio button

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.9.1 and have free shipping working just fine. It does require the user to move the cursor over the one and only Free Shipping radio button and click it first before it is enabled. How can I have it so that it is automatically selected?

Answer (score 2):

You can do following :

1) Go to your template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml, inside foreach, check if current foreach item is free_shipping, add checked="checked" for that checkbox and keep it hidden.